# Game crashes on adding an TMX object layer

Tags: android, andengine

When I try to add an object layer to my `TMX` map file, the game crashes when attempting to load it, however when I remove the object layer and leave the other tile layers it loads normally. What could be preventing me from loading my object layer enabled`TMX`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <map version="1.0" orientation="orthogonal" width="40" height="40" tilewidth="32" tileheight="32">
 <tileset firstgid="1" name="tileset1" tilewidth="32" tileheight="32">
 <image source="grfx/game/tmx/tileset1.png" trans="ff00ff" width="512" height="384"/>
  </tileset>
 <layer name="ground" width="40" height="40">
 <properties>
 <property name="hit" value="false"/>
 </properties>
 <data encoding="base64" compression="gzip">
 H4sIAAAAAAAAC+3OoREAMAgEsDes0P1HxbAD5S4iPpWkAICvvLH98AMAAACuamnyeMoAGQAA
</data>
</layer>
<layer name="hill" width="40" height="40">
 <properties>
  <property name="hit" value="false"/>
  </properties>
  <data encoding="base64" compression="gzip">
              H4sIAAAAAAAAC+3VsQkAIAxFwWytG+jYZgJBQVJ4B79P8SARAPBWy/XqIzZGblYfwbWTvipaPOlLi/zEbwAAAF5bWZ4LagAZAAA=
</data>
</layer>
 <objectgroup name="hills" width="40" height="40">
  <properties>
  <property name="hit" value="true"/>
  </properties>
 <object x="101" y="452" width="51" height="56"/>
 <object x="360" y="323" width="51" height="53"/>
 <object x="454" y="453" width="57" height="53"/>
 <object x="70" y="645" width="50" height="57"/>
 <object x="260" y="394" width="56" height="86">
 <ellipse/>
</object>
</objectgroup>
</map>
```

This one works:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <map version="1.0" orientation="orthogonal" width="40" height="40" tilewidth="32" tileheight="32">
  <tileset firstgid="1" name="tileset1" tilewidth="32" tileheight="32">
     <image source="grfx/game/tmx/tileset1.png" trans="ff00ff" width="512" height="384"/>
       </tileset>
      <layer name="ground" width="40" height="40">
       <properties>
       <property name="hit" value="false"/>
        </properties>
          <data encoding="base64" compression="gzip">
    H4sIAAAAAAAAC+3OoREAMAgEsDes0P1HxbAD5S4iPpWkAICvvLH98AMAAACuamnyeMoAGQAA
         </data>
       </layer>
        <layer name="hill" width="40" height="40">
         <properties>
         <property name="hit" value="false"/>
          </properties>
         <data encoding="base64" compression="gzip">
       H4sIAAAAAAAAC+3VsQkAIAxFwWytG+jYZgJBQVJ4B79P8SARAPBWy/XqIzZGblYfwbWTvipaPOlLi/zEbwAAAF5bWZ4LagAZAAA=
         </data>
        </layer>
       </map>
```

Comment: Can you post a Logcat?

Comment: Thanks for your response, it seems the problem is with polygon objects on the object layer, but wiht rectangles it works as normal. Do you know if polygons are supported objects as yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm adding this as an answer, for the sake of clarity and as a workaround for my unfamiliarity with formatting markup for comments.

Polygons are not currently supported by AndEngine.  The post [here on the AndEngine forum](http://www.andengine.org/forums/features/polyline-and-polygon-from-tmx-t6688.html) confirms this.  In the thread though, a member mentions his own custom branch that has the support, to a point.

> My isometric branch (see my sig) can read in polygon and polylines,
>   but its up to you to implement drawing or collisions. I've not got any
>   examples on how to do this, but I can provide a rough idea how to
>   translate pixel coordinates(which is how TMX stores these points) to
>   the scene.

His GitHub repository is located [here](https://github.com/Niffy/AndEngine).